# Calculating what day a specific date will fall on in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, algorithm, date, math

I want to be able to input any date i.e. 1/17/2019 (MM/DD/YYY format) and calculate what day of the week that would be using jQuery. I tried writing some basic functions, but my code is pretty terrible because I'm just learning jQuery. I want my output to look like "That date will be (day of the week), (month selected), year" so, if the inputted date is 1/17/2019 the output would read "That date is Thursday, January 17 2019"

Currently, I have two fields for the user to input the year, #yearField which is the first two digits of the year and #centuryField which is the last two digits of the year (I need better naming conventions, I know) and a selection box allowing the user to select the month from a list. I'm also unsure of how to parse the users month input into a number i.e. "January" = 1 "February" = 2 etc.

```
<script>
setup = function() {
calc = function() {
    // alert("Hey there!");
    // var tip = document.getElementById("checkField").value * 0.20;
    // document.getElementById('tipArea').innerHTML = "The tip is $" + tip;


    var year = $("#yearField").val();
    var century = $("#centuryField").val();
    var level = $("#monthSelect").val();
    var day = $("#dateField").val() + $("#yearField").val() + ($("#yearField").val() * .25) + ($("#centuryField").val() * .25) - ($("#centuryField").val() * 2) ; 





    var message = "That date will be " + $("#monthSelect").val() + " " + day + " " + year + century;
    $("#displayArea").html(message).css("color", "blue").css("font-size", "50px");

}


$("#calcButton").click(calc);

}

$(document).ready(setup);

</script>
```

Currently, that outputs "That date will be January 1002016.75 2019" when the user inputs the date as "100" the #yearField as "20" and the #centuryField as "19"

Comment: The native JavaScript `Date` object has a [function to get the day of the week](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a JavaScript `Date` object by passing in the values `year, month, day`. Note that you have to `-1` from the month, because months, like most things in JavaScript, begin with `0`. (`January = 0, December = 11`)

Once you have your date, you can use `Date.toLocaleString()`, which allows you to pass an `options` object with your formatting preferences.

```js
$("#btnGetDate").on("click", function() {
  //Get values from the inputs
  var year = $("#txtYear").val();
  var month = $("#ddlMonth").val();
  var day = $("#txtDay").val();

  //Format the date and output it
  var formattedDate = formatDate(year, month, day);
  console.log(`Your date is ${formattedDate}`);
});

function formatDate(year, month, day) {
  //Create a Date object using the values
  var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

  //Define how you want the date to be formatted
  var options = {
    weekday: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric"
  };

  //Format the date according to our options
  return date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
}
```

```css
input,select {margin-right: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Month
<select id="ddlMonth">
  <option value="01">January</option>
  <option value="02">February</option>
  <option value="03">March</option>
  <!-- and so on... -->
</select>

Day
<input id="txtDay" type="number" placeholder="dd">

Year
<input id="txtYear" type="number" placeholder="yyyy">

<button id="btnGetDate">Output Date</button>
```

Of course, this could use some guardrails/validation around entering invalid dates, entering the day or year in the incorrect format, etc, however I will leave that portion up to you!